# Adding context sensitive help to my Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, chm

I have developed a fairly complex Excel workbook.  Now I want to document it.  I discovered MS compiled HTML file.  So I wrote a document in Word that contains detailed information about each sheet in my workbook.  I saved it and use the MS HTML Help Workshop and the chmProcessor that I downloaded from the web.  Eventually I got it to work and created the .CHM file.  In my workbook I wrote a sub that looks like this:

```
Sub getHelp()
    Dim currentPath As String
    currentPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.Help (currentPath & "\LogicAndAccuracyTesting.chm")
End Sub
```

It all works.  From my workbook, I set {f1} to call getHelp and it does display my documentation.

Help also support the HelpContextID property.  I want to use it to display the exact topic that the user has asked for help.

How do I get the HelpContextID from my Word document?  If I save the .docx file as a .htm file, how can I get the HelpContextID?  How do I use 2 components of office (Word and Excel) to create a tightly integrated help system?  I'm not a professional developer at this point so I don't want to spend a lot of money on a professional help authoring system.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the version of excel you are using? I'll have a look to your question later to give an answer.

Comment: I use Excel 2019.

Answer (score 3):

`HelpContextID` has a learn curve when using CHM files. ChmProcessor makes it a bit difficult too. ChmProcessor is not well suited for using contextID's. But give it a try (the man's way).

- First use the **Generate help project** option
- Copy the file names generated into the foobar.hhp file (open by e.g Notepad++) to a file named `alias.h`
- Edit the lines into the format described at: [ALIAS and MAP files](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_context-id.htm)
- Create a `map.h` file as described (see link above).
- Save the file as `alias.h` and `map.h` in same folder as your help project file *.hhp

Add following section to your e.g foobar.hhp file:

```
[ALIAS]
#include alias.h

[MAP]
#include map.h
```

**Save the files you created in another place too!**

Compile your help project by using HTMLHelp Workshop or other freeware tools like [FAR HTML](http://www.help-info.de/en/FAR/far.htm).

As for test case only I add a CHM help file call below. Please note, you'll get one help viewer window showing the default topic by this code (edit the code for your needs). After a click to the help button (in German "Hilfe") the topic related to HelpContextID:=20010 is shown in another window.

```
Function TestMacro()
'----------------------------------------------------------------
' Display a message box with a help button linked to a help topic
'----------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim currentPath As String
    currentPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.Help HelpFile:=currentPath & "\CHM-example.chm", HelpContextID:=0

    '--- MsgBox sample code -------------------------------------
    MsgBox "The 'Hello World' message for testing this function!.", _
    Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbMsgBoxHelpButton, _
    HelpFile:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\CHM-example.chm", _
    Context:=20010
End Function
```

[image]